# Can't set text box value inside javascript sliding div

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am very new to asp.net and javascript (first ever project) so it may be something very simple. I have a vertical slider courtesy of http://do-web.com/jcontent/demo. Within each div are clickable divs which when clicked should update the value of a text box.

This work perfectly if the text boxes are outside of the vertical slider.

However i want the textboxes to be on the final slide. When i place them here only the last text box is updated regardless of how many slides there are (the example below only has two but have tried with 6 and it's only ever the last text box which updates.

I also wanted to add Required Field Validation to the text boxes but this doesn't work either when they are within the slider.

I assume there is some scope issues i'm unaware of. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/jcontent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcontent.0.8.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("div#demo").jContent({
                orientation: 'vertical',
                width: 960,
                height: 360,
                easing: "easeOutCirc"
            });
        });
    </script> 
    <script>
        function option(i, x) {
            $(i).val(x);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="page">       
            <div id="main">     
                <div id="demo">
                    <a title="" href="#" class="prev" style="font:12px arial black; width:50px; left:0px; margin-right:425px;">PREV</a>
                    <a title="" href="#" class="next" style="font:12px arial black; width:50px; right:0px; margin-left:425px;">NEXT</a>                    
                    <div class="slides" style="border-top:solid 1px #0078AD">
                        <div style="position:relative;">
                            <div class="title">Jack Size</div>
                            <div id="slide1option1" onclick="option('.option1t','C00');" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:0; height:340px; width:480px; cursor:pointer;">
                                <img id="C00" src="images/slides/slide1_1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/slides/slide1_1_focus.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/slides/slide1_1.jpg'" border="0"/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slide1option2" onclick="option('.option1t','C01')" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:240px; height:340px; width:480px; cursor:pointer;">
                                <img id="C01" src="images/slides/slide1_2.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/slides/slide1_2_focus.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/slides/slide1_2.jpg'" border="0"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="position:relative;">
                            <div class="title">Jack Type</div>
                            <div id="slide2option1" onclick="option('.option2t','TS')" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:0; height:340px; width:480px; cursor:pointer;">
                                <img id="TS" src="images/slides/slide2_1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/slides/slide2_1_focus.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/slides/slide2_1.jpg'" border="0"/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slide2option2" onclick="option('.option2t','KS')" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:320px; height:340px; width:480px; cursor:pointer;">
                                <img id="KS" src="images/slides/slide2_2.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/slides/slide2_2_focus.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/slides/slide2_2.jpg'" border="0"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                        <div style="position:relative;">
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" class="option1t" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>   
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" class="option2t" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                                                            
                </div>  

            </div> 
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you click `next` / `prev` in your slider, the slides are removed from the DOM and appended or prepended to the slider in a different position.

So you are clicking a button on the first page. Your textboxes are updated just fine, but when you switch slides, they are recreated and considered two brand new completely empty textboxes.

You need to store your options in another place and populate your textboxes when you actually get to that slide. There are multiple ways you can do this, by storing it in data attributes, hidden input fields or just in a global javascript array.

I have used the last one in the example below:

**HTML**

Change your `onclick` to:

```
onclick="option('option1t','C01')"
```

Notice I removed the `.` before `option1t`.

**JS**

Here I fill the textboxes with the options stored in the `selected` array each time you click `Next`.

```
var selected = [];

function option(i, x) {
    selected[i] = x;
}

$("document").ready(function () {

    $("div#demo").jContent({
        orientation: 'vertical',
        width: 360,
        height: 360,
        easing: "easeOutCirc"
    });

    $('.next').click(function () {
        if (typeof selected['option1t'] != 'undefined') {
            $('.option1t').val(selected['option1t']);
        }
        if (typeof selected['option2t'] != 'undefined') {
            $('.option2t').val(selected['option2t']);
        }
    });
});
```

And you'll find a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ucn9/)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for the great explanation and the help!

Comment: Any idea why the required field validation wont work on the text boxes?

Comment: Very hard to say. `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` shouldn't have any problems with the textboxes being removed and added to the DOM again. You should probably add them to your code example in your question for further help, but it might be better to post a new question about it.